# c++ passing ptrs around

Tags: c++, pointers, unique-ptr

Still having lots of problems grasping pointers, i've tried to not use them, but i'm not sure how to best accomplish the following.

I have two classes `Point` and `Ray`, I'm also sure that there is probably already an implementation of a point class somewhere that I should be using instead. So I have these two classes, and i'm trying to create a ray, and eventually pass that along to something else, but i get an error: `Thread`: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)` when I create the ray the way i'm doing it, and try to access it.

```
class Point {
    public:
    float x;
    float y;
    Point();
    Point(float x, float y);
    ~Point();
};

Point::Point() {
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
}

Point::Point(float xPos, float yPos) {
    x = xPos;
    y = yPos;
    std::cout << "point created at: " << x << ", " << y << std::endl;
}

Point::~Point() {
    std::cout << "point destroyed" << std::endl;
}

class Ray {
public:

    std::unique_ptr<Point> origin;

    float angleInRadians;
    float length;

    float slope();
    Point* pointAtDistance(float percentage);
    Point* pointAtYPos(float yPos);

    Ray(Point& origin, float angleInRadians, float length);
    ~Ray();
};

Ray::Ray(Point& origin, float angleInRadians, float length) {
    origin = std::move(origin);
    angleInRadians = angleInRadians;
    length = length;
}

float Ray::slope() {
    return tanf(angleInRadians);
}

Point* Ray::pointAtDistance(float percentage) {
    return new Point(origin->x + (length * percentage) * cosf(angleInRadians), origin->y + (length * percentage) * sinf(angleInRadians));
}

Point* Ray::pointAtYPos(float yPos) {
    float B = origin->y - (slope() * origin->x);
    return new Point((yPos - B) / slope(), yPos);
}

Ray::~Ray() {
    std::cout << "point released" << std::endl;
    origin.release();
    std::cout << "ray destroyed" << std::endl;
}
```

The third line is where the error comes in.

```
std::unique_ptr<Point> point(new Point(x,y));
std::unique_ptr<Ray> ray(new Ray(*point, M_PI/4, 100));
std::cout << "RAY origin: " << ray->origin->x << ", " << ray->origin->y << std::endl;
```

Comment: Can we see how you use these classes? The most probable error I can see is missing copy constructors and assignment operators. If you use pointers as data member, you have to define these to specify how is each pointer to be handled.

Comment: Also, returning a raw pointer is usually not good practice. Why do you want to use pointers in this example? I believe if you just used object instances (not pointers), all your errors would just go away...

Comment: That's literally everything in the class. I'm pretty new to this stuff and kind of just going through by myself and trying to put something together.

Comment: I tried not to use pointers, but was getting errors I didn't know how to handle. That would be my preferred method if you could point me in the right direction

Comment: I understand that it is everything there is in the class. The problem, though, is probably in the way you use that class.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed the std::move... I think I would just make things simpler by not using any pointers at all. Let me post an answer for you.

Comment: another detail - `angleInRadians = angleInRadians;` just assigns a value to itself - C++ cannot know what you mean by which variable if they are both named the same, and will just use one of them (for a lack of simpler explanation, lets say the "closer" one - i.e., the one in the parameter list)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this should work - I just literally removed all pointers from your code and used instances instead. At your level of C++ knowledge, pointers are almost always unnecessary.

```
class Point {
    public:
        Point();
        Point(float x, float y);
        ~Point();

        float x;
        float y;
};

Point::Point() {
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
}

Point::Point(float xPos, float yPos) : x(xPos), y(yPos) {
    std::cout << "point created at: " << x << ", " << y << std::endl;
}

Point::~Point() {
    std::cout << "point destroyed" << std::endl;
}

class Ray {
    public:
        Ray(const Point& origin, float angleInRadians, float length);
        ~Ray();

        float slope();
        Point pointAtDistance(float percentage);
        Point pointAtYPos(float yPos);

        Point origin;

        float angleInRadians;
        float length;
};

Ray::Ray(const Point& o, float a, float l) : origin(o), angleInRadians(a), length(l) {
}

float Ray::slope() {
    return tanf(angleInRadians);
}

Point Ray::pointAtDistance(float percentage) {
    return Point(origin.x + (length * percentage) * cosf(angleInRadians), origin.y + (length * percentage) * sinf(angleInRadians));
}

Point Ray::pointAtYPos(float yPos) {
    float B = origin.y - (slope() * origin.x);
    return Point((yPos - B) / slope(), yPos);
}

Ray::~Ray() {
    std::cout << "ray destroyed" << std::endl;
}
```

Hopefully this will get you started. Good luck with the rest of the assignment!

Comment: Another question, if i were to store a `vector` of `Rays`s, would it be possible to store them without pointers? std::vector<Ray>?

Answer (score 0):

You code has two problems: The first problem which leads to the crash you are experiencing, is the fact that your assignments in the `Ray` constructor are noops. In the line

```
origin = std::move(origin);
```

both occurences of `origin` refer to the same variable (which is the variable that's local to the function). Consequently, the variables in your class remain un/default-initialized. For a smart pointer, default initialization means that it contains a NULL pointer, which segfaults when you access it.

However, changing your constructor to use initializer lists which avoids this problem

```
Ray::Ray(Point& origin, float angleInRadians, float length) :
    origin(&origin), angleInRadians(angleInRadians), length(length)
{}
```

won't remove the crash due to the second problem in your code: You construct two different `unique_ptr<>`s for the same object: The first one is the `unique_ptr<>` called `point`, the second one is the `unique_ptr<>` called `origin` in the class `Ray`. So, your program tries to destroy the `Point` object twice, once when the variable `point` goes out of scope, second when the variable `ray` goes out of scope.

When using the standard C++ libraries "smart" pointers, it is crucial never to convert a smart pointer to a naked pointer/reference and then recreate a smart pointer from that naked pointer/reference. You are safe as long as you only ever assign smart pointers from smart pointers or pass smart pointers by reference, but you must never create two smart pointers that do not know of each other for the same object. Even with `shared_ptr<>`, this must never be done. If you do, both will try to do their work, and you will get a crash (hopefully).

---

Sidenote (just my 2 cents of biased wisdom):
I believe that pointers are best understood not by using C++ and its "smart" pointers, but by writing programs using the old style, naked pointers of C. C-style pointers are really a very simple, very powerful, albeit quite dangerous thing. And they need some experience to master. Learn first what needs to be done to use naked pointers in a safe way; once you can do this, you'll have all the necessary understanding to use smart pointers in your sleep.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to disagree with your conclusions - in the original code, he passes a reference to an instance held in an unique_ptr to the constructor (which is a valid thing to do). Then, he calls `origin = std::move(origin);`, which does not do anything, because both `origin`s refer to the same non-const reference. Therefore, he does not create two unique_ptrs to the same instance. (btw, that is not a trivial thing to do, until you revert to raw pointers somewhere in the process). Because the `origin` member variable stays default-constructed, it is always NULL = its use segfaults.

Comment: And as for use of raw pointers, I am really sorry, I have to disagree as well - in modern C++ (i.e., 11 or 0x), you don't really need to use raw pointers at all. All their concepts are represented using a form of smart pointer, with semantics and implementation that makes their misuse significantly harder. It is much easier to learn how to use a concept from compiler errors than from segfaults (which might be reported on a completely different place than where the error originally was, and/or hard to reproduce).

Comment: @martin_pr You are right, the default constructed `unique_ptr<>` is the reason for the crash the OP experienced, I updated the answer accordingly. However, the code `unique_ptr<int> foo(new int); unique_ptr<int> bar(&*foo);` *is* erroneous and will try to free the `int` twice. Yes, there is a naked pointer in the process, albeit a short lived one. Still everybody using smart pointers needs to be aware that this must never be done. And I never said that it is a good practice to use raw pointers in C++, only that it is good to learn their use for the sake of learning the implementation details.

Comment: You are correct that this would be a problem. However, I am sorry, but that problem is _not present_ in the code OP provided (nowhere in the code he creates a raw pointer out of a variable or reference). Moreover, in your corrected code, you assign a non-const reference directly to a unique pointer, which is not a valid operation and will not even compile.

Comment: @martin_pr Right, I simply forgot that ampersand :-( The point is, that once the `Point` is passed by naked reference, there is simply no valid way to put it into a "smart" pointer anymore.

Comment: I am sorry, but again, not exactly correct - the [`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) does not have an [assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator%3D) that would allow to assign a raw pointer, I believe to avoid simple mistakes like that. The code has to be `origin = std::unique_ptr<Point>(&originArg);`.

Comment: @martin_pr Ok, I rewrote this part to use initializer lists now. Hope it makes you happy ;-)